# Video freezes but audio plays on YouTube

Tags: youtube

For the past two days YouTube on my OnePlus 6 has been glitching. Everytime I click on a video I can hear the audio **but the video doesn't play** (it doesn't go black, it just freezes with the audio playing in the background). Also, the new update allows me to swipe right to see the next video, something which isn't there on my brother's phone even though he has the updated version of YouTube (as per Play Store).

I deleted cache and storage in settings and also restarted my phone. The app works fine but again goes back to glitching after a while. The glitch starts with the home screen and slowly stops the operation of all the other features on YouTube.

Can someone help me with this? The problem seems to be only on my phone because the app works fine on my friend's OnePlus 6. I have checked the answers for [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/61037/96277) and they didn't work for me.

**Note**: I am using the latest software and an updated YouTube.

Comment: Try changing the video quality. Start from low quality to high and check if the issue remains.

Comment: What phone is it? Have you tried disabling and enabling the app?

Comment: @shamsul, I uninstalled and reinstalled the app. Not sure what you mean by disabling and enabling the app. I tried everything, I'm just worried if it's a bug that crept into my phone when I visited certain shady sites. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @shamsul, it's a OnePlus 6

Comment: I think, system app such as Youtube cannot be uninstalled completely (without root access). If you uninstall, it is essentially uninstalling the updates.I own a One plus 6 (oreo 8.1 OS). By disabling I meant, going to settings->apps, then click youtube, then find the disable button. Disable the app, then the button will change to Enable. Now, enable the app.

Comment: @shamsul, did that. Now do I update the YouTube app?

Comment: Are still facing the freezing problem?

Comment: @shamsul, I'm still facing the problem. The home page freezes but audio plays sometimes. Otherwise the whole thing freezes

Comment: @shamsul, so this is what problem is. After disabling and enabling the app, the swipe feature wasn't present even after updating the app. Everything worked fine. Once the feature came, the glitch arose when I used WiFi but doesn't when I use mobile data.

Comment: I guess, it is basically a bug. Until then, use the Old version. Also, you can find some recent version apk in the internet.

Comment: How did the bug come? Is it some virus or something? Should I be worried? And any chance when it'll correct itself?

Comment: I don't it is a severe bug/virus. It's just sometimes new version of an app shows some problems with limited mobile devices(there are numerous android devices out there). I hope it will get fixed soon.